# Compressing/hashing a bit vector of any length to a defined length

Tags: algorithm, hash, language-agnostic, compression

Given an input bit-string, I am looking for some compression/hashing algorithm to generate an output of a length of, lets say, 64 bits, with minimal false positives.

One way to achieve this is using Bloom Filters. However, as I understand, bloom filters use *k* hash functions, and for minimal false positive rate, the number *k* depends on the input bitstring length, which in my case, is not fixed.

Also, I cannot use cryptographic hash functions as they are computationally expensive.

Any hints/references ?

Thanks

Comment: So basically, any hash function. Perhaps you could supply a bit more detail? What's known about the inputs? How many are there? What's the severity of a collision (= what do you use the hashes for)? Why can't you use cryptographic hash functions? (SHA-2 can be like 100 MiB/s on an old Intel Core 2, that's plenty fast for most purposes.)

Comment: If you don't need the hashes to be cryptographically secure... why not use the low-order 64 bits, and left-fill with 0's as needed?

Comment: @delnan Because the hash needs to be calculated every now and then in a network, depending on the traffic, Cryptographic hash function might lead to a bottleneck. About the inputs, its only known that they are bit strings of more than >64 bits in this example.

Comment: @Patrick87 I had thought of such a random hash function, for e.g. taking XOR of bits and resulting in 1st bit of the hash, XOR of each alternate bits and resulting in next bit of the hash and so on. But there are no mathematical background to justify the false positive rates or efficiency.

Comment: What on Earth are you talking about? I'm talking about the identity function, which is a perfect hash function (no collisions at all) in the ideal case, and for your case, has the smallest number of collisions possible. It is also highly efficient. No randomization involved. Just let the hash of a bit string be equal to the bit string, mod 2^64. Done. What do you mean by "false positive" rate? If you mean the number of collisions and/or degree of collisions, it's exceedingly simple to reason about: if you have N*(2^64) things to hash, you'll have 2^64 collisions of degree N-1.

Comment: This is optimal and justified by the Pigeonhole principle: if you have N pigeons and M holes, there's at least one hole with ceiling(N/M) pigeons in it. Indeed, the only downside of the identity function as a hash function is that it's fairly straightforward to invert (left as an exercise), so it's not suitable for cryptographic applications.

Comment: @Patrick87 This argument all bit patterns in those lower 64 bits are equally likely. This is not always the case. It's a reasonable assumption lacking further information about the inputs, but you should state it.

Comment: @delnan Ah right, of course. If the probabilities differ significantly from "uniformly random modulo 2^64", this could be less than optimal (for some distributions, exceedingly so!). Excellent point... took me a minute to get it.

Comment: Ok, Clearing up a bit, the hash are required for inputs which are 'spatially divided' event space in a publish-subscribe system. For e.g. we have 2 attributes in the PubSub system x and y. And as the number of subscribers increase, we divide the x and y axes, so as to create 'subscription spaces'. These subscription spaces are denoted by binary strings. In the first division, we get 4 subscription spaces as 00 01 10 and 11. As the number of subscriptions increase, the string lengths increase.

Comment: What is suggested by @Patrick87 is definitely an option, but it depends on how the subscriptions are spread out. It might turn out to create a lot of collision, or may be very less. But then I guess its the same for any hash function and will be heavily dependent on the input patterns.

Comment: @gaganbm Have you tried searching for it on google? The first thing I get is [this ycombinator thread](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=4036696). One of the suggestions is [MurmurHash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MurmurHash).

Comment: Also, Bloom filters are completely unrelated: they are structures based on hash functions, not hash functions themselves. They have an entirely different purpose. What you want is, by its definition, a hash function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [CityHash](http://code.google.com/p/cityhash/) family of hash functions are extremely fast, being non-cryptographic, and have excellent hash properties.